# I am struggling to remove both 6's from this array

Tags: javascript, singly-linked-list

I am trying to solve a problem that needs me to remove the number 6 from an array.
I know how to remove the last 6 using `pop()` but I tried `splice()` with `indexOf()` to remove index 2 and 6 but no luck. This is from a singly linked list challenge.

The expected output should be [1,2,3,4,5].
My output is currently [1,2,6,3,4,5].

```
var removeElements = function(head, val) {
  let array = [1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  this.val = (this.val === 6 ? this.val : array.pop(this.val));
  this.head = (head === this.val ? head : this.next);
  console.log(array);
};
```

Comment: what is `this` here?

Comment: This code isn't really doing anything;  You suggest that you are trying to remove elements from an array, but you are re-defining the array every time you call this function.

Comment: also, if your intent is to ask how to do manually some of the functionality that is built in to JavaScript like filters, you might want to ensure you word the question to make that clear;  as it stands, people are going to suggest filter and might even close the question as a duplicate because it's not obvious that you are trying to solve a coding challenge.

Comment: Hi folks, the challenge instructions are very poor to understand for me.

Comment: The  this is referring from what I understand as the current element in a array of numbers. It is from a singley list challenge which I can link for you if you like. It is meant as practice after learning about nodes and node architecture. I think I might have to use node methods to like assigning the head node and tail node and the link between each number. Each number in the array is  the data section of each node. In order to remove the nodes with 6 as their data I must make a method that does that. Using array methods might be the wrong approach....just learnt this stuff lol.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6].filter(v => v !== 6);
console.log(array);
```